# Bloody dirt texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, shaders, texture-painting

Im trying to get a bloody dirt texture/effect like the reference I have here. The terrain is easy with some noise and displacement but how can I can that blood soaked look?[image]

Comment: Are you using a displacement modifier, or are you doing displacement via shader?

Comment: Im using a displacement modifier with a clouds texture and scatter add on for the rocks.

Answer (score 5):

First I would make a "splotch" by warping the vectors of a Spherical Gradient Texture with a Noise Texture (softened by mixing with white first) and then cutting it off with a ColorRamp.

[image: Blood1]

Then, use that "splotch" as a mix factor between your main texture and a red color (set to multiply to ""lay" the red over the base texture). Also, use it as a mix factor between your roughness texture and a dark color, to make the blood "shiny":

[image: Blood2]

Comment: Ah, So much simpler than I would have thought. Thanks Chris!